# Possibility to Ignore warning in pipeline?

Tags: warnings, biztalk, pipeline, custom-pipeline-component

Here at the project we've set our projects to treat warnings as errors, but when setting that option on a BizTalk project we've noticed we had the following warning:

> Stage 'Validate' has multiple 'X' components.

It is by design we put 2 the same components on the same pipeline. 
We were wondering if we could disable these warnings in c# you can do something like this with your code `#pragma warning disable 0649`

Is there any possibility to ignore these warnings in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to suppress BizTalk projects warning. All you can do is to avoid them